# Page redirects to the previous page during jquery Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I have hosted a jquery mobile sample app in following url. http://intelliwins.com/map Now when i click on show button on the top it supposed to call a web service and retrive data from database and show the markers in google maps based on the latitude and longitude we get from DB.  Now when i click on the Show button it redirected to the previous page in browser. Even when i check with firebug i couldn't find out the answer Please help.

Comment: It works for me. Adds "Wefe Tower" and "my home" to the map and list below. Google Chrome, Windows 7 Pro

Comment: @Devin It works in some browser. But failed to work in Android browser, Windows Phone IE and also on firefox 22.0 which i'm testing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never tell the browser to halt processing, you simply bind:

```
onclick="get_marker()"
```

You either need to add `return false;` after the `get_marker()` or change it to `return get_marker()` and have that method `return false`. Otherwise jquery mobile is going to come in and process the click after you're done.

*also, FWIW, using iPhone emulator I get "Error" and "0" in two alerts, then continues on to `history.go(-1)`.*